# My search results are only showing 5 posts?

Tags: php, search

This issue isn't related to the get_posts() default value of 5 because I don't use that function.

Also WP-pagenavi is set to 10 posts.

I'm quite bad at PHP so any help is nice.

[image]

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
                <header class="page-header">
                <span class="search-page-title"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', stackstar ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></span>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $post_format = et_pb_post_format(); ?>

                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' ); ?>>

                <?php
                    $thumb = '';

                    $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_width', 1080 );

                    $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_height', 675 );
                    $classtext = 'et_pb_post_main_image';
                    $titletext = get_the_title();
                    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
                    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                    et_divi_post_format_content();

                    if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote' ) ) ) {
                        if ( 'video' === $post_format && false !== ( $first_video = et_get_first_video() ) ) :
                            printf(
                                '<div class="et_main_video_container">
                                    %1$s
                                </div>',
                                $first_video
                            );
                        elseif ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'gallery' ) ) && 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_thumbnails_index', 'on' ) && '' !== $thumb ) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
                            </a>
                    <?php
                        elseif ( 'gallery' === $post_format ) :
                            et_pb_gallery_images();
                        endif;
                    } ?>

                <?php if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <?php if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio' ) ) ) : ?>
                        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php
                        et_divi_post_meta();

                        if ( 'on' !== et_get_option( 'divi_blog_style', 'false' ) || ( is_search() && ( 'on' === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_pb_use_builder', true ) ) ) ) {
                            truncate_post( 270 );
                        } else {
                            the_content();
                        }
                    ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->
            <?php
                    endwhile;

                    if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) )
                        wp_pagenavi();
                    else
                        get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
                endif;
            ?>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: why you said it's not related to `get_posts()` ? and this page is showing the results and not the query

Comment: @TemaniAfif Because other people were talking about this in other solutions but I dont see get_posts() in my index.php. What do I need to show?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Divi theme. If you want to change the number of posts showing on archive, search, category pages, you will need to make the change in theme options. Use a value of -1 to show all posts.

[image: screenshot of Divi Theme Options]